# Over a commutative ring, $AB = I_n$ and $BA = I_m$ implies that $m = n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $A \in M_{n \times m}(R)$, $B \in M_{m \times n}(R)$ with the property that $AB = I_n$ and $BA = I_m$, prove that $n = m$.

I’m aware of a proof involving traces in the case that $R$ is a field of characteristic zero, but cannot think of / know of a proof for this more general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, and let $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$. If $C=(c_{ij})\in M_{p\times q}(A)$, define $\bar{C}=(\overline{c_{ij}})_{ij}\in M_{p\times q}(k)$.

It is not difficult to see that $\overline{C_1C_2}=\overline{C}_1 \overline{C}_2$, with obvious notation.

Now if $AB=I_n$ and $BA=I_m$, then $\bar{A}\bar{B}=I_n\in M_n(k)$ and $\bar{B}\bar{A}=I_m\in M_m(k)$. Since $k$ is a field,  a classical result of linear algebra tells you that $n=m$.

Comment: Oh my goodness, whenever I saw results such as the existence of maximal subgroups or ideals I would kinda tune out, thinking ‘why is this useful’... the fact that any non-trivial ring can be quotiented to give a field now feels extremely useful.